# How to select option from the radio and display it?

Tags: php

Here is my code, I'm not able to display the option which is selected in radio. I have made the radio box using bootstrap and even I have used
**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label for="gender" class="gender">Gender:</label><br>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" name="male" for="inlineRadio1" id="male">Male</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" name="female" for="inlineRadio2" id="female">Female</label>
              </div>
            </div>  <input class="btn btn-outline-info" name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit2">
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
echo "hello";
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
  echo $_POST['inlineRadioOptions'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is alright, kindly make sure that the php code is on the same page, mostly on top, or if php code is on another page than make sure to add the link of the file in action="form.php"  like this inside form tag.

Answer (score 0):

### Your not using a Form

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input type="radio" name="radioBTN" id="" value="Hello World">
   <input type="submit" name="signup">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['signup'])) echo $_POST['signup'];
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm using form just didn't mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Do Like This With Form Tag with it's Submit Button Value and Check Post Data By print_r();

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="UserForm" method="POST">

<div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="gender" class="gender">Gender:</label><br>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
            <label class="form-check-label" name="male" for="inlineRadio1" id="male">Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
            <label class="form-check-label" name="female" for="inlineRadio2" id="female">Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>  <input class="btn btn-outline-info" name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit2">

</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
 // print_r($_POST); // Optional for Checking Value
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit']) && $_POST['btnsubmit'] == "Submit")
{
  echo "hello";

  echo $_POST['inlineRadioOptions'];
}
?>
```